# Python: Taking a random element from a list and removing it writtin in a class

Tags: python, list

Im a beginner in coding and I´ve got a quick question.
I´ve writtin a code to pick a random user from a roaster and put it in one team, then it picks another user and puts it into another team. The problem is the roaster consists of 6 people, my programm only picks 2 for each. How do I solve this?
My code looks like this.

```
import random


def random_list_element_taker(list_name,  new_list, new_list2):
    import random
    for i in list_name:
        x = random.choice(list_name)
        new_list.append(x)
        list_name.remove(x)
        y = random.choice(list_name)
        new_list2.append(y)
        list_name.remove(y)


roaster = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6"]
team1 = []
team2 = []
random_list_element_taker(roaster, team1, team2)
print(team1)
print(team2)
```

Comment: The way you're iterating is incorrect. You're looping each name in the roster, but then each iteration you're assigning two random names to a team.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be removing items from a list while you're iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good try. The thing is with for loops, once you remove an element from the list you're basing it off of, `i` doesn't change, so it will always skip 1 per element you remove.

basically : If a list is 6 elements long, and you remove the 4th, the 5th goes to the 4th position whenever `i` has already been to the fourth position and is moving onto the 5th, so the fourth gets skipped

I wouldn't recommend using `def` for small projects like this, because it makes it a bit more complicated, but if you like it that way, it's all good.

How I would do it :

```
import random


roaster = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6"]
random.shuffle(roaster) # randomly shuffles the whole list, without need of for loop

team1 = roaster[:len(roaster)//2] # Gets the second half of the list
team2 = roaster[len(roaster)//2:] # Gets the first half of the list

print(team1)
print(team2)
```

**EDIT : this will only work with even players.**

Comment: Thank you very much, I´ve figured out what my problem is but made it way more complicated then I needet to. Now I have 43 lines of code while u made it perfect in 11.

Comment: @Greezdee We all were there at some point, just keep practicing.

Comment: @Greezdee if you found this answer to be right, could you mark it as the answer? I'm new and trying to get as much reputation as possible.

Comment: @Greezdee Btw to set a response as an answer, you click the check mark under the score

Comment: Sorry that it took me so long, there u go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the for loop takes an iterable object and you are mutating the list for that iterable list. You are changing the values as you loop. Try instead a while loop (Note:this will delete all elements in the list_name). If you want to keep them just copy the list.

```
import random


def random_list_element_taker(list_name,  new_list, new_list2):

    while list_name:
        x = random.choice(list_name)
        new_list.append(x)
        list_name.remove(x)

        y = random.choice(list_name)
        new_list2.append(y) 
        list_name.remove(y)


roaster = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6"]
team1 = []
team2 = []
random_list_element_taker(roaster, team1, team2)
print(team1)
print(team2)
```